# Clausula Begin - End

Tags: sql, sql-server

***Tengo una tabla de mas de 4 millones de registros en la cual quiero que actualice un campo de la tabla consultando cada registro mediante sentencias IF ELSE dentro de una clausula "BEGIN - END" pero no logro hacer que suceda, alguien que me apoye.***

```
BEGIN
DECLARE @DIAS INT;
DECLARE @MESES INT;
DECLARE @AÑOS INT;

SELECT 
    @DIAS = floor((((cast(datediff(day, fecha_nac, DATEFROMPARTS ( Anho, Mes, dia )) as float)/365-(floor(cast(datediff(day, fecha_nac, DATEFROMPARTS ( Anho, Mes, dia )) as float)/365)))*12)-floor((cast(datediff(day, fecha_nac, DATEFROMPARTS ( Anho, Mes, dia )) as float)/365-(floor(cast(datediff(day, fecha_nac, DATEFROMPARTS ( Anho, Mes, dia )) as float)/365)))*12))*(365/12))+1 ,
    @MESES = floor((cast(datediff(day, fecha_nac, DATEFROMPARTS ( Anho, Mes, dia )) as float)/365-(floor(cast(datediff(day, fecha_nac, DATEFROMPARTS ( Anho, Mes, dia )) as float)/365)))*12) , 
    @AÑOS = floor(cast(datediff(day, fecha_nac, DATEFROMPARTS ( Anho, Mes, dia )) as float)/365)

FROM
    BDHISMINSA.DBO.ARCHIVOPLANO

SELECT @DIAS; 
SELECT @MESES; 
SELECT @AÑOS; 
IF @DIAS > 0 AND @MESES = 0 AND @AÑOS = 0 --UPDATE ONLY DAYS
    BEGIN
        update BDHISMINSA.DBO.ARCHIVOPLANO
        set ED=convert(int, @DIAS)
    END
ELSE IF @DIAS > 0 AND @MESES > 0 AND @AÑOS = 0 --UPDATE ONLY MONTHS
    BEGIN
        update BDHISMINSA.DBO.ARCHIVOPLANO
        set ED=convert(int, @MESES+50)          
    END
ELSE IF @DIAS > 0 AND @MESES > 0 AND @AÑOS > 0 --UPDATE ONLY YEARS
    BEGIN
        update BDHISMINSA.DBO.ARCHIVOPLANO
        set ED=convert(int, @AÑOS+100)
    END
ELSE IF @DIAS IS NULL AND @MESES IS NULL AND @AÑOS IS NULL --UPDATE EMPTY FECHA_NAC FIELDS
    BEGIN
        update BDHISMINSA.DBO.ARCHIVOPLANO
        set ED=''
    END END
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: oh, wow...a menos que la tabla `ARCHIVOPLANO` tenga solo una fila de datos....esto está todo mal hecho, sorry

Comment: como puedo realizar que recorra fila por fila y que entre en esas sentencias if a evaluar si cumple

Comment: justamente **no** debes hacer que esto recorra por fila

Comment: lo hago por fila porque es de la fila misma donde salen los valores de **@dias** **@mes** y **@años** para actualizar en esa misma fila un campo "ED", otra sugerencia

Comment: para que recorra fila por fila usa cursors pero es mala práctica, son muy pesados, creo que puedes meter bucles for o while

Comment: También tienes una mezcla con los tipos de datos; qué tipo de dato tiene la columna `ED`?

Comment: Yo creo que mejor que esto, usa el boton [edit] y explica que estas tratando de hacer con este SP... Vemos que tuviste un intento, pero no se entiende que tratas de hacer...

Comment: @gbianchi sí se entiende :D, pero necesito saber el tipo de dato

Comment: @Lamak ok, yo ni entendi que trata de hacer, pero confio en vos plenamente...

Comment: @Iria cuando tengas un rato, te pasas por el [chat]?

Comment: @Lamak el tipo de dato de la columna 'ED' es nvarchar(255)

Comment: @Iria justamente estuve haciendo con cursores pero no hay cuando acabe, va como 20 min, ya lo cancelé

Comment: cursores es mala práctica, bloquea las tablas y son pesados por ello, pero si no se te ocurre nada... algo es algo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hay varios problemas con lo que estás tratando de hacer. En primer lugar, estás tratando de recorrer los datos de la tabla fila a fila, pero sin hacer un loop. Con lo cual, lo que estás haciendo es poniendo un valor arbitrario en tus variables, y luego haciendo un `UPDATE` sobre la tabla completa.

Independiente de esto, en SQL siempre debes tratar de evitar hacer operaciones fila a fila si no es necesario. En tu caso, la solución es simple:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  *,
            Dias = floor((((cast(datediff(day, fecha_nac, DATEFROMPARTS ( Anho, Mes, dia )) as float)/365-(floor(cast(datediff(day, fecha_nac, DATEFROMPARTS ( Anho, Mes, dia )) as float)/365)))*12)-floor((cast(datediff(day, fecha_nac, DATEFROMPARTS ( Anho, Mes, dia )) as float)/365-(floor(cast(datediff(day, fecha_nac, DATEFROMPARTS ( Anho, Mes, dia )) as float)/365)))*12))*(365/12))+1 ,
            Meses = floor((cast(datediff(day, fecha_nac, DATEFROMPARTS ( Anho, Mes, dia )) as float)/365-(floor(cast(datediff(day, fecha_nac, DATEFROMPARTS ( Anho, Mes, dia )) as float)/365)))*12), 
            Años = floor(cast(datediff(day, fecha_nac, DATEFROMPARTS ( Anho, Mes, dia )) as float)/365)
    FROM BDHISMINSA.DBO.ARCHIVOPLANO
)
UPDATE CTE
SET ED = CASE
            WHEN Dias > 0 AND Meses = 0 AND Años = 0 THEN convert(int, Dias)
            WHEN Dias > 0 AND Meses > 0 AND Años = 0 THEN convert(int, Meses+50)
            WHEN Dias > 0 AND Meses > 0 AND Años > 0 THEN convert(int, Años+100)
            WHEN Dias IS NULL AND Meses IS NULL AND Años IS NULL THEN ''
         END
;
```

Comment: Justo estaba escribiendo una respuesta similar. Me quedan las dudas del cálculo, pero al menos la respuesta soluciona el problema de la mejor forma.

Comment: @LuisCazares sí, no quise meterme en el cálculo de lo que está haciendo, o la lógica específica...

Comment: Gracias @Lamak, tu solución funcionó correctamente.